# using java generics to extend interfaces or just bad design?

Tags: java, generics

I'm still new to the Java world (former C++ programmer). I designed an Interface hierarchy to force my implementation to @Override the methods in the interfaces. Now I'm in some kind of "how to do this in java". All bellow are interfaces.

```
XMLDecoder      HTTPDecoder
    |                |
    ------------------
            |
        SSODecoder                  UserStuff
            |                           |
            -----------------------------
                         |
                         |
                     SSOBinding
                         |
                         |
                     Assertion
```

Now the fun part is I have an object implementing SSOBinding and another implementing Assertion. My problem is both **HAVE** to implement every method in XMLDecoder **AND** HTTPDecoder. I believe I have some pretty design but for that :(

Can Java Generics help me solve this problem? Something like:

```
Assertion<XMLDecoder> anAssertion = new Assertion<XMLDecoder>();
anAssertion.OnlyMethodsInXMLDecoder();
```

At least that's what I can think of for now but not having any success in implementing this.

Thanks a lot!

---

### EDIT 1

Sorry for my poor explanation.

The hierarchy is not upside down (on top are the bases).

SSODecoder is my problem. I know it can have either require ***XMLDecoder*** OR an ***HTTPDecoder***. Forget about SSOBinding. So I could have an implementation:

```
class AssertionImpl1 implements Assertion {
       // Only implementing XMLDecoder
}

class AssertionImpl2 implements Assertion {
       // Only implementing HTTPDecoder
}
```

The only difference for these to would be the method they need to implement for the decoder.

Comment: That hierarchy doesn't look right.  You're going to have to describe what these interfaces do, i.e. why does an SSODecoder need to extend both XMLDecoder and HTTPDecoder, and why does an Assertion inherit from SSOBinding, UserStuff, etc.  Or, did you draw the tree upside-down, in which case similar questions apply.

Comment: I think that my answer still holds with your hierarchy upside down. Give both XML and HTTP Decoders a common API, and delegate.

Comment: Thanks, even with little comment I understood what you meant. So I removed the XMLDecoder and HTTPDecoder. They where upside down anyways. The common interface is now SSODecoder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No.

I'm guessing that you got your inheritance tree wrong: If not all instances of SSODecoder need to implement the methods in  HTTPDecoder and  XMLDecoder, then SSODecoder is not a subinterface of both.

You should look into an alternative design, where HTTPDecoder and  XMLDecoder are strategies that are used by the SSODecoder. Force them to have the same interface, and make SSODecoder delegate to them... whatever responsibility they have.

That way, your call will be something like:

```
Assertion anAssertion=new Assertion(new XMLDecoder());
```

Comment: That about what I just did! Removed the XML and HTTP interfaces and I create a decoder Implementing SSODecoder. I was confused. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in which direction your "extends" relation goes, but if `Assertion` extends `SSOBinding`, `SSOBinding` extends `SSODecoder` and `SSODecoder` extends `XMLDecoder` and `HTTPDecoder` then if two objects implements `SSOBinding` and `Assertion` respectively, *both will implement every method in `XMLDecoder` and `HTTPDecoder`.